# How to connect two ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#AdminCreateNewUserSubmit').on('click',function(){
        $("#admincreatenewuserform").ajaxForm(
        {
            target:     '#admincreatenewuserformcenter', 
            url:        'update.php', 
            success:    function(data) 
            {
                $("#admincreatenewuserformcenter").html(data);
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This code works, but I need to add another request when given data.

So I have tried the following:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#AdminCreateNewUserSubmit').on('click',function(){
        $("#admincreatenewuserform").ajaxForm(
        {
            target:     '#admincreatenewuserformcenter', 
            url:        'update.php', 
            success:    function(data) {
            $("#admincreatenewuserformcenter").html(data);

                $.post("update.php", { cmd:'adminrefreshtabusers' },
                    function(data){ 
                        $('#AdminMenuTabStatisticGenerate').html('');
                        $('#AdminMenuTabStatisticGenerate').html(data);
                    }
                );

            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But this code does not work...

What is the right way to connect two ajax requests?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @LeoLoki Despite the questionable indentation, this code is syntactically valid. Can you post a link to a demo site, or a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: ERROR - when second data not add in div `AdminMenuTabStatisticGenerate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form request gets sent fine, you're just updating the wrong output field. `#AdminMenuTabStatisticGenerate` is on the statistics page. Instead, update `#users` or one of its children.